# parse_and_bind() for keys other than <tab>

Tags: python, python-3.x, readline, libreadline

Is it possible to use "?" for tab-complete besides tab key in python?
python allows to use  key with parse_and_bind('tab: complete'),
but I don't see any option for binding other keys like '?';

thanks

Comment: anyone has done this before ? please share.